# Load data object when package is loaded

Tags: r

Is there a way to automatically load a `data` object from a package in memory when the package is loaded (but not yet attached)? I.e. the opposite of lazy loading? The object is used in one of the package functions, so it needs to be available at all time.

When the package is set to `lazydata=false`, the data object is not exported by the package at all, and needs to be loaded manually with `data()`. We could use something like:

```
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg){
  data(mydata, package = pkg)
}
```

However, `data()` loads the object in the global environment. I strongly prefer to load it in the package environment (which is what lazydata does) to prevent masking conflicts.

A workaround is to bypass the `data` mechanics completely, and simply hardcode the object in the package. So the package `myscore.R` would look like

```
mymodel <- readRDS("inst/mymodel.rds")
myscore <- function(newdata){
  predict(mymodel, newdata)
}
```

But this will lead to a huge packagedb for large data objects, and I am not sure what are the consequences of that.

Comment: I would very much like to know the answer! I am working with the `nloptr` package, which uses package data in one of its functions, and hence doesn't work when the package is loaded but not attached ...

Comment: could you use `data(mydata, package=pkg, environment=parent.env(environment()))` in your `.onLoad` file?

Comment: @BenBolker That seems to work. Although feels a bit hacky. E.g. when lazydata=true, R will overwrite the mydata object with its own version when the package is attached. Also the data object is not automatically visible to the user; you would need to manually export it.

Comment: If you have a `.Rprofile` you could try an `if` statement or a function there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say

> The object is used in one of the package functions, so it needs to be available at all time.

I think the author of that package should really *NOT* use `data(.)` for that.
Instead he should define the object inside his /R/  either by simple R code in an R/*.R file,
or by using the `sysdata.rda` approach that is explained in the famous first reference for all these question,
["Writing R Extensions"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).  In both cases the package author can also export the object which is often desirable for other users as in your case.

Of course this needs a polite conversation between you and the package author, and will only apply to the next version of that package.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to post this since it seems to work for my use case.

`.onLoad()` is:

```
 function(lib,pkg)
    data(mydata, package=pkg, 
           environment=parent.env(environment()))
```

Also need `Imports: utils` in `DESCRIPTION` and `importFrom(utils, data)` in `NAMESPACE` in order to pass R CMD check.

In my case I *don't* need the data object to be visible to the user, I need it to be visible to one of the functions in the package.  If you need it visible to the user, that's going to be even harder (I think) because as far as I can tell you can't export data, just functions.  The only way I've thought of to export data is to export a wrapper function for the data.

Comment: If you use this solution, make sure you don't set `lazyData=true`, because then R will overwrite `mydata` with its own version once the package gets attached.

Comment: hmm.  I'm not sure I understand the issue here (maybe it doesn't apply in my use case?), but I'll think about it ...

Comment: If the data is visible to the package but not the user, then you should be using `sysdata.rda` not `data/`