# How to load explicitly some datasets in an R package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a package with 3 datasets: data1, `data2`, `data3`.

I want that my package only loads automatically `data1`, but no `data2` and `data3`. If I use `lazydata = true` ALL datasets are loaded and I want to be selectively.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "load"?  Do you mean loaded into memory or available to users?

Comment: @NathanWerth `data1`: Loaded in memory (automaticaly).
`data2` and `data3`: Loaded only using command `data(data2)` or `data(data3)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354850/load-data-object-when-package-is-loaded

Comment: @SRivero, I think that the answers on this post are not conclusive. Even one of them said that "If you need it visible to the user, that's going to be even harder". And that's what I'm looking for, I want `data1` to be available to users at the moment they load the package, and just the opposite with `data2` and `data3`.